# preg_replace / foreach to change url's in text

Tags: php, foreach, preg-replace

In a piece of text we have several links, found with:

```
$regex = '\b(http://www.domain.com/)[-A-Z0-9+&@#/%?=~_|!:,.;]*[-A-Z0-9+&@#/%=~_|]';
```

We would like to change these urls into new ones, like:

http://www.domain.com/news/item.php?ID=12321&TYPE=25 into: /news/page/$arttype-$artID/

$url gives a listing of several of those url's, but we can't seem to update them in $message.

This is the code so far:

```
$string = "$message";

function do_reg($text, $regex) {
    preg_match_all($regex, $text, $result, PREG_PATTERN_ORDER);
    return $result[0];
}

$A =do_reg($string, $regex);
foreach($A as $url) {
    $check = parse_url($url, PHP_URL_QUERY);

    preg_match("/ID=([^&]+)/i", $check, $matches);
    $artID = $matches[1];

    preg_match("/TYPE=([^&]+)/i", $check, $matches);
    $arttype = $matches[1];

    preg_replace("$url", "/news/page/$arttype-$artID/", $text);
}
```

Does anyone know how to update all the unique url's found in $message?

-------using V-tech's code----------------

```
$message = " 
<li><strong><a href="http://www.domain.com/news/item.php?ID=12321&TYPE=25" target="_blank">Link 1</a></li>
<li><strong></strong><a href="http://www.domain.com/news/item.php?ID=12300&TYPE=2" target="_blank">Link 2</a></li>
<li><a href="http://www.domain.com/news/item.php?ID=12304&TYPE=2" target="_blank">Link 3</a></li>
<li><a href="http://www.domain.com/news/item.php?ID=12314&TYPE=2" target="_blank">Link 4</a></li>";

$pattern = "/(http:\/\/www\.domain\.com)\/news\/item\.php\?ID=([^&]+)&TYPE=(\d+)/g";
$replacement = "\${1}/news/page/\${2}-\${3}/";
preg_replace($pattern, $replacement, $message);
echo "$message ";
```

Comment: Oh what in the world is happening here ? You know that this script is extremely slow since you've put several `preg_` in a loop ? I'll point out: **1-** that your regex is lacking delimiters, which mean it's invalid. So please enable error reporting, it saves you headache. **2-** You may use `preg_replace_callback()` to do all of that in one go.

Comment: Sorry about that. It is the first time working with this having several matches etc. Still no clue how to fix it though :-)

Comment: @KJS As `HamZa` pointed out, you are lacking delimiters. You are not closing your `\b` --- for example: `preg_match("/\bweb\b/i"` --- Consult (and taken from) the PHP manual on `preg_math()` => http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-match.php

Comment: Thanks, but that is not really the problem. The problem is that the $url's are not updated to /news/page/$arttype-$artID/. Just can't see where it's going wrong.

Comment: @KJS [A quick fiddle](https://eval.in/44370), no time to explain. Sorry about that :-)

Comment: Thanks so much HamZa!!! Very cool scripting you did there. Works great for us, just as the method V-tech send us. You guys are great, thanks for the support!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What about doing it in one command?

```
$pattern = "/(http:\/\/www\.domain\.com)\/news\/item\.php\?ID=([^&]+)&TYPE=(\d+)/";
$replacement = "\${1}/news/page/\${2}-\${3}/";
$result = preg_replace($pattern, $replacement, $message);
```

Basically it cuts three pieces of information (scheme://domain, ID value and TYPE value) out and cooks new url by inserting these three pieces into the $replacement string.

Where `ID=([^&]+)&TYPE=(\d+)` assumes, that ID value can be anything (beware of html entities starting with &) till &. TYPE value here is assumed to be numerical. So change it to your needs.

**Updated**: removed g flag from $pattern, preg_replace() result put in $result

Comment: Thanks V-tech, but somehow it still isn't working. I've added code and your solution above. Maybe you can see what's going wrong. (of course the " are \" in php)

Comment: Use something other than / for the pattern delimiter, so you don't have to escape all those literal /'s. # or ~ would work well: `$pattern = "#(http://www\.domain\.com)/news/item\.php\?ID=([^&]+)&TYPE=(\d+)#"`

Comment: Thank you too V-tech! Both your and HamZa's solution worked perfectly. Thanks for the support everybody!

Answer (score 1):

`From : http://www.domain.com/news/item.php?ID=12321&TYPE=25

 To   : http://www.domain.com/news/page/25-12321/`

```
$string_start = '<li><strong><a href="http://www.domain.com/news/item.php?ID=12321&TYPE=25" target="_blank">Link 1</a></li>
<li><strong></strong><a href="http://www.domain.com/news/item.php?ID=12300&TYPE=2" target="_blank">Link 2</a></li>
<li><a href="http://www.domain.com/news/item.php?ID=12304&TYPE=2" target="_blank">Link 3</a></li>
<li><a href="http://www.domain.com/news/item.php?ID=12314&TYPE=2" target="_blank">Link 4</a></li>';

$string_end   = $string_start;
$string_end   = preg_replace("/(https|http):\/\/(w{0,3}\.{0,1})(domain\.com)\/news\/item\.php\?ID=([0-9]*)(&amp;|&)TYPE=([0-9]*)/", "$1://$2$3/news/page/$6-$4/", $string_end);
```

Comment: Thank you too D3F4ULT. I learned a lot today, thanks to all of you.